# How to define a property whose type in database is bit?

Tags: c#

I have a column named source of type bit in my database. but I want to get set its value in my program. how can I do that? I know it was a simple doubt but I was little bit confused. Do I have to use byte as type while setting this or not?

Comment: Remember a byte is 8 bits they aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [bool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) for representation bit from database:

```
public bool MyBitDbProperty {get;set;}
```

If you use [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) than use reader.GetBoolean(position) for bit type.

If you use any rdbms(like [linq to sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)), bit will mapped to bool by default.

Comment: vs2008 already does it in the dataset.xsd if i'm correct if the database is sql server of sql server compact

Answer (score 5):

The bit database type will contain the values 0 and 1, and normally (you've not stated RDMS) corresponds nicely with the bool or Boolean types in c#.